# Difference between id and name attributes in HTML

Tags: html, attributes

What is the difference between the `id` and `name` attributes? They both seem to serve the same purpose of providing an identifier.

I would like to know (specifically with regards to HTML forms) whether or not using both is necessary or encouraged for any reasons.

Comment: There is very good thread on this topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id

Comment: This most comprehensive answer is [Farhan Shirgill Ansari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html/27963591#27963591) (not saying anything about its correctness).

Answer (score 773, accepted):

The `name` attribute is used when sending data in a form submission.  Different controls respond differently.  For example, you may have several radio buttons with different `id` attributes, but the same `name`.  When submitted, there is just the one value in the response - the radio button you selected.

Of course, there's more to it than that, but it will definitely get you thinking in the right direction.

Comment: would you please describe a littel more on it..When submitted, there is just the one value in the response - the radio button you selected.

Comment: other than radio button are there any usage ?? I think it should have great differences other than that ???

Comment: @Prageeth: The difference is that a "name" transfers from the browser to the server and can be different than the "id".  There are many reasons people might want that difference.  For example, your server-side language/framework may need the submitted values to have certain names, but your javascript works best with something completely different in the ids.

Comment: To put it very informally, `id` is what your frontend (CSS, JS) works with, while `name` is what your server receives and can then process. This is basically what Greeso's answer says.

Comment: It might be better to say: *The name attribute is **required*** when sending data... instead of: *The name attribute is **used** when sending data...* since any form data missing the **name** attribute will not be transmitted (or indeed will not be processed at all according to the HTML spec)

Comment: I've always used id to be unique, and name to not be unique, and I've used them both pervasively outside of forms for years. Incredibly useful, allows uniqueness and grouping and both are reference-able via js. Come to find out I'm doing it wrong, but data-name would be allowed... wasn't there a time that name was the only way to group, maybe HTML 3 or 4?

Comment: I think name is a somewhat dead attribute, although in certain types of tags it is actually useful but for the most part id and name attributes are sort of auto reference as the same type of attribute for things like anchors and queries.  Of course you can't expect them to be monotonous.  In the very old days some "experts" preached to use both, so if you see old html, sometime you see every id attribute is sitting along side a name attribute.  That misguided guideline has thankfully fallen away years ago.

Comment: @IsmaelHarun While the code you used may seem to treat name and id as the same (particularly if you're writing a SPA using AJAX and no form submissions), name and id are still very different.  Name is required if you want to send field values back to the server on a form submission. Id is used for normal JavaScript DOM operations.

Comment: Please be more specific than "there's more to it than that"...

Comment: @LukeHutchison: This answer is 13 years old, so I don't really want to touch it. Please, keep reading the other comments, or ask a new question if you don't find what you need.

Answer (score 395):

Use `name` attributes for form controls (such as `<input>` and `<select>`), as that's the identifier used in the `POST` or `GET` call that happens on form submission.

Use `id` attributes whenever you need to address a particular HTML element with CSS, JavaScript or [a fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It's possible to look up elements by name, too, but it's [simpler and more reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351570/what-is-the-difference-between-javascripts-getelementbyid-and-getelementsbyna) to look them up by ID.

Comment: This was hugely clarifying. So, might I infer, then, that "name"  is almost a representation of the parameter "identifier" sent across to the server? This question is partly answered by the accepted answer but is not put in those terms.

Comment: @Thomas: There is no necessary tie between `name` and `id` at all. The identifier uniquely identifies a particular HTML element on the page. The `name` attribute of an HTML form element, by contrast, does not have to be unique, and often isn't, such as with radio buttons or pages with multiple `<form>` elements. It is traditional to use the same string for `name` and `id` where both are used on a single HTML element, but nothing makes you do this.

Comment: @WarrenYoung
what about the name attribute of the form tag.
As far as I know, its value must also be unique, so I am confused why there is a name attribute for this tag that does the same thing as the id attribute.
In my opinion, the name attribute for the form tag is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, the id attribute should be used.

I haven't tested it, but I think if you have multiple forms with the same name, the last form overwrites the previous ones. Apart from the fact that it's not actually allowed, but how much HTML code is out there that is not compliant with the rules.

Answer (score 192):

## Here is a brief summary:

- `id` is used to **identify the HTML element through the *Document
  Object Model*** (via JavaScript or styled with CSS). `id` is expected
  to be unique within the page.
- `name` corresponds to the *form* element and **identifies what is posted
  back to the server**.

Answer (score 35):

The way I think about it and use it is simple:

**id** is used for CSS and JavaScript/jQuery (it has to be unique on a page).

**name** is used for form handling on the server when a form is submitted via HTML (it has to be unique in a form - to some extent, see [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3748030)'s comment below).

Comment: Not entirely true - the **Name** attribute doesn't have to be unique in a form, as it can link radio buttons together.

Comment: Also, it may surprise you, but PHP is not the only server language in the world.

Comment: @seesharper - That's funny. I even voted you up! Well, yes, that does not surprise me :)

Answer (score 28):

See *[id= vs name=](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/htmlforms.html#IDVSNAME)*:

> What’s the difference? The short answer is, use both and don’t worry about it. But if you want to understand this goofiness, here’s the skinny:
>
> id= is for use as a target like this: `<some-element id="XXX"></some-element>` for links like this: `<a href="#XXX"`.

> name= is also used to label the fields in the message send to a server with an HTTP (HyperText Transfer Protocol) GET or POST when you hit submit in a form.
>
> id= labels the fields for use by JavaScript and Java DOM (Document Object Model).
> The names in name= must be unique within a form. The names in id= must be unique within the entire document.
>
> Sometimes the name= and id= names will differ, because the server is expecting the same name from various forms in the same document or various radio buttons in the same form as in the example above. The id= must be unique; the name= must not be.
>
> JavaScript needed unique names, but there were too many documents already out here without unique name= names, so the W3 people invented the id tag that was required to be unique. Unfortunately older browsers did not understand it. So you need both naming schemes in your forms.

*Note*: attribute "name" for some tags like `<a>` is not supported in [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5).

Comment: A bit confusing... and I think wrong in some points. Isn't it this: `name` is important for `<input>` tags in a `<form>` submission as the parameters are used in the HTTP, and `id` is merely a unique identifier

Comment: Also, this (unregistered) user is linking to his own page (the link on his profile says http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ ). I don't know if that's a problem for SO but given the rather confusing snippet it feels inapropriate.

Answer (score 16):

The *ID* tag - used by CSS, define a **unique** instance of a div, span or other elements. Appears within the JavaScript DOM model, allowing you to access them with various function calls.

The *Name* tag for fields - this is unique per **form** -- unless you are doing an array which you want to pass to PHP/server-side processing. You can access it via JavaScript by name, but I think that it does not appear as a node in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or some restrictions may apply (you cannot use .innerHTML, for example, if I recall correctly).

Comment: radio buttons *must* share the same name to behave properly - it's not unique per form.

Comment: My mistake. Though to clarify, for text inputs, text areas and etc, name tags are used to identify them. Not necessary unique.

Comment: *Tag*? Isn't an *attribute*?

Answer (score 14):

Generally, it is assumed that **name is always superseded by id**. This is true, to some extent, but not for **form fields and frame names**, practically speaking. For example, with form elements, the *name* attribute is used to determine the **name-value pairs to be sent to a server-side program** and should not be eliminated. ***Browsers do not use id in that manner***. To be on the safe side, you could use the *name* and *id* attributes on form elements. So, we would write the following:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
     <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" />
</form>
```

To ensure compatibility, having matching *name* and *id* attribute values when both are defined is a good idea. However, be careful—some tags, **particularly radio buttons, must have nonunique *name* values, but require unique id values.**

Once again, this should reference that *id* is not simply a replacement for *name*; they are different in purpose. Furthermore, do not discount the old-style approach, a deep look at modern libraries shows such syntax style used for performance and ease purposes at times. Your goal should always be in favor of compatibility.

Now in most elements, the *name* attribute has been deprecated in favor of the more ubiquitous id attribute. However, in some cases, particularly form fields (`<button>`, `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`), the *name* attribute lives on, because it continues to be required to set the name-value pair for form submission. Also, we find that some elements, notably frames and links, may continue to use the *name* attribute, because it is often useful for retrieving these elements by name.

There is a clear distinction between *id* and *name*. Very often when *name* continues on, we can set the values the same. However, *id* must be unique, and *name* in some cases shouldn’t—think radio buttons. Sadly, the uniqueness of *id* values, while caught by markup validation, is not as consistent as it should be. CSS implementation in browsers will style objects that share an *id* value; thus, we may not catch markup or style errors that could affect our JavaScript until runtime.

This is taken from the book *JavaScript - The Complete Reference* by Thomas-Powell.

Comment: Another reason not to get in the habit of just making id match name: you may have two forms on a page which need to submit the same data (e.g. two search fields). In this case, the `name` should be the same (the server-side code doesn't care which was submitted), but the `id` must be different (because it must be unique within the whole page).

Answer (score 13):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>

    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? The question was *"What is the difference between the id and name attributes?"*. Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23203151/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 10):

#### *name* vs. *id*

---

*name*

- Name of the element. For example used by the server to identify the
  fields in form submits.
- Supporting elements are `<button>`, `<form>`, `<fieldset>`, `<iframe>`,
  `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, `<map>`,
  `<meta>`, and `<param>`
- Name does not have to be unique.

*[id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)*

- Often used with CSS to style a specific element. The value of this
  attribute must be unique.
- Id is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). Global attributes can be used on all elements, though the attributes may have no effect on some elements.
- Must be unique in the whole document.
- This attribute's value must not contain white spaces, in contrast to
  the class attribute, which allows space-separated values.
- Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.'
  may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4.
  Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start
  with a letter for compatibility.

Comment: I’ve seen `name` attributes used in style elements. I assume this is invalid?

Answer (score 10):

```html
<body>
<form action="">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <button>Submit!</button>
</form>
</body>
```

As we can see here, "id" and "for" elements are interconnected. If you click on the label (Username) then the input field will be highlighted (this is useful for mobile users and is considered as a good practice).

On the other hand, the "name" element is useful while submitting the form. Whatever you enter in the input field it will be displayed on the URL. Please see the attached image.

[image: Image of URL]

Answer (score 9):

The forum thread below has answers to the same basic question, but basically, *id* is used for scripting identification and *name* is for server-side.

*[id vs. name attribute for HTML controls](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t115115-id-vs-name-attribute-for-html-controls.html)*

Answer (score 9):

`name` is deprecated for link targets, and invalid in HTML5. It no longer works at least in the latest Firefox (v13). Change `<a name="hello">` to `<a id="hello">`.

The target does not need to be an `<a>` tag. It can be `<p id="hello"`> or `<h2 id="hello">`, etc. which is often cleaner code.

As other posts say clearly, `name` is still used (needed) in forms. It is also still used in META tags.

Comment: Do you mean "name is deprecated for link tags" instead of "name is deprecated for link targets"?

As a matter of fact, the link target can be an iframe. If you don't specify the name attribute for that iframe, the target attribute does not work for the link. That behaivor remains still for all browsers and is HTML5 compliant.

Comment: I am here trying to figure out how to make a link *anchor*, as in the marker for where you go *to*  when you have a URL that ends in "#something".  the best i can tell, in html before 4, it must be <a name="something">.  In html 4, it's <a name="something" id="something"> (matching),  and in html 5, <a id="something">, although id can be a "global attribute" on anything.  What i can't figure out is whether name in addition to id is *tolerated* in <a> in html 5.  ok experiment w whatever setup i happen to have...

Comment: While the `a` tag `name` attribute is deprecated, it is still supported by browsers including Firefox, so the answer is incorrect. Yes, for an anchor (target location) you should now use id on the element (`<h2 id="hello">`), but this wasn't really what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 7):

The ID of a form input element has nothing to do with the data contained within the element. IDs are for hooking the element with JavaScript and CSS. The name attribute, however, is used in the HTTP request sent by your browser to the server as a variable name associated with the data contained in the value attribute.

For instance:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="user" value="bob">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="abcd1234">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the form data will be included in the HTTP header like this:

**If you add an ID attribute, it will not change anything in the HTTP header. It will just make it easier to hook it with CSS and JavaScript.**

Answer (score 3):

ID is used to uniquely identify an element.

*Name* is used in forms. Although you submit a form, if you don’t give any name, nothing will will be submitted. Hence form elements need a name to get identified by form methods like "get or push".

And only the ones with the *name* attribute will go out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using the form's own submit method to send information to a server (and are instead doing it using JavaScript) you can use the *name* attribute to attach extra information to an input - rather like pairing it with a hidden input value, but it looks neater because it's incorporated into the input.

This bit does still currently work in Firefox although I suppose in the future it might not get allowed through.

You can have multiple input fields with the same name value, as long as you aren't planning to submit the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

Id:

1. It is used to identify the HTML element through the [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (DOM) (via JavaScript or styled with CSS).
2. *Id* is expected to be unique within the page.

*Name* corresponds to the form element and identifies what is posted back to the server.

Example:

```
<form action="action_page.php" id="Myform">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>The "Last name" field below is outside the form element, but still part of the form.</p>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" form="Myform">
```

Answer (score 2):

In all the time this question has been around, I am chagrined (and perhaps a bit saddened) that nobody has thought to mention [accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) which, though always important, has been steadily gaining support amongst both management and software engineers (just from my personal observations; no hard data to back that up).

One statistic I can provide is this ([source](https://blog.usablenet.com/midyear-report-app-and-web-accessibility-lawsuits-on-track-for-record)):

[image: Accessibility lawsuits]

So awareness of accessibility shortcomings show a steadily growing trend. The same reference mentions that, from those numbers, one can observe that at least one lawsuit is filed *every hour*!

So how does accessibility weigh in on `name` vs `id`?

According to the [World Wide Web Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) (W3C):

> The `for` attribute of the label must exactly match the `id` of the
> form control.

Answer (score 1):

Based on personal experiences and according to the [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) description for attributes:

ID is a *global attribute* and applies to virtually all elements in HTML. It is used to uniquely identify elements on the Web page, and its value is mostly accessed from the frontend (typically through JavaScript or jQuery).

*name* is an attribute that is useful to specific elements (such as form elements, etc.) in HTML. Its value is mostly sent to the backend for processing.

*[HTML Attribute Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp)*

Answer (score 1):

There is no literal difference between an *id* and *name*.

*name* is an identifier and is used in the HTTP request sent by the browser to serve as a variable name associated with data contained in  the value attribute of the element.

The *id* on the other hand is a unique identifier for browser, client side and JavaScript. Hence the form needs an *id* while its elements need a *name*.

*id* is more specifically used in adding attributes to unique elements. In DOM methods, *Id* is used in JavaScript for referencing the specific element you want your action to take place on.

For example:

```
<html>

<body>
    <h1 id="demo"></h1>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Same can be achieved by name attribute, but it's preferred to use *id* in a form and *name* for small form elements like the input tag or select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an interesting use of the *id* attribute. It is used within the <form> tag and used to identify the form for <input> elements outside of the </form> boundaries so that they will be included with the other <input> fields within the form.

```
 <form action="action_page.php" id="form1">
     First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 <p>The "Last name" field below is outside the form element, but still part of the form.</p>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `name` and `id` is targetable by `#` so not sure why ID was mentioned for this task exclusively.

I often **Inspect** those attributes to create specific links to bookmark (where clicking on header with mouse cursor to do the same is not provided for some reason) such as the *Option File Inclusions*
section of *MySQL 5.6 4.2.2.2 Using Option Files* documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html#option-file-inclusions

where it's defined as `<a name="option-file-inclusions"></a>` (with absolutely no forms involved).

I think, the `name` attribute is also older than `id` in HTML.