# Simple javascript not working - frustrating!

Tags: javascript, html

can someone please help me get this simple countdown timer to work, firebug is complaining: document.counter is undefined

```
<script> 
<!-- 
// 
 var milisec=0 
 var seconds=30 
 document.counter.d2.value='30' 

function display(){ 
 if (milisec<=0){ 
    milisec=9 
    seconds-=1 
 } 
 if (seconds<=-1){ 
    milisec=0 
    seconds+=1 
 } 
 else 
    milisec-=1 
    document.counter.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec 
    setTimeout("display()",100) 
} 
display() 
--> 
</script> 


<form name="counter"><input type="text" size="8" 
name="d2"></form>
```

Comment: you didn't set the form's id tag, you set just the name.

Comment: It's enough, the code will work with name as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indeed, `document.counter` *doesn't* exist because your script is being called before the HTML DOM is loaded.

You need to put your JS inside a function that will be invoked `onload`.

Instead of calling `display()` put this at the bottom of your script:

```
window.onload = display;
```

Also, the `<!--` `-->` comments haven't been needed around JS code for at least 10 years...

Comment: You may also find the following discussion usefull: [Best Practice: Access form elements by HTML id or name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute)?

Answer (score 0):

Place the form before the script...

Answer (score 0):

Either have the script at the end of the page, or:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var milisec=0;
    var seconds=30 ;
    document.forms["counter"].elements["d2"].value='30';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move to JQuery to help with cross browser issues
[JQuery $(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)