# Should I access a form by name, id or by array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practice: Access form elements by HTML id or name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute)

The forms on my site all have "id" attributes as follows...f0,f1,f2..., and this is how I access them.  My understanding is that Javascript creates an aray that hold the forms and I can access them this was as well.

By id:

```
var a='f0';
var c=document.forms[a].elements;
```

By array index:

```
var c=document.forms[0].elements;
```

By name:

```
var a='f0';
var c=document.forms[a].elements;
```

Which way is better, I just picked by id as a starting point.

Comment: Just read the W3C DOM 2 HTML spec regarding [document.forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064), which is an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) whose the members can be referenced by *index*, *id* or *name*.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty abstract - collections, nodes and what not I wish there was a Cliff Notes.  A collection is a list of nodes.  What is a node?  An element like <a>??

Comment: Yes. The DOM specs are language neutral. Elements are nodes, but not all nodes are elements (e.g. text nodes, attribute nodes, etc.). Some DOM interfaces return a NodeList, the HTML specs extend that for HTML documents to include HTMLCollections, which is a NodeList of HTML elements.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate....keep closing posts which are SIMILAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID and Name are 2 different things:

```
var a='f0';
var c=document.forms[0].elements[a];
```

is accessing the element by name

example

```
<input name="f0" value="value" />
```

accessing by id is doene this way

```
var a='f0';
var c=document.getElementById(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have more than one on the page I use the id, there is less room for confusion and its more expressive and intuitive for any developers that are in the code after you.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with what you've got - ID is more explicit.  Index is nearly arbitrary and will cause headaches if the code is ever changed.