# javascript download link not working

Tags: javascript, html

i have been trying a lot to download exe files using javascript ,i have did it using radio buttons before but now i dont have any idea how should i download .the scenario is there are 3 checkboxes admin,security,security1 ,and i am supposed to check whether which combination of checkboxes are seslected after that on clicking on download button different zip files need to be downloaded .

```
 <button onclick="
if(!this.form.admin.checked&&!this.form.security.checked&&!this.form.security1.checked)
{
document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML='Make atleast one selection';

}
else if (this.form.admin.checked&&this.form.security.checked&&this.form.security1.checked == 1)
{
alert('security32 and admin and security64');
}
else if (this.form.security.checked&&this.form.security1.checked == 1)
{
 alert('security64 and security32');
}
else if (this.form.admin.checked&&this.form.security.checked == 1)
{
alert('security32 and admin');
}
else if (this.form.admin.checked&&this.form.security1.checked == 1)
{
alert('security64 and admin');
}
else if (this.form.admin.checked == 1)
{
alert('admin is checked');
}
else if (this.form.security.checked == 1)
{
alert('security 32 is checked');
}
else if (this.form.security1.checked == 1)
{
alert('security64 is checked');
}
return false;

">Submit</button>
```

i have replaced alert by location.href="images/download.exe"; to check whether it is getting downloaded by no luck

the code that was working for the radio button was

```
<input value="1" type="radio" id="1" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)">
function displayForm(c)
{
var radios = document.getElementById("1").value;
location.href="images/WismanWeb 32 bit.exe";
}
```

Comment: Instead of simply registering on SO and posting a question you should at least _try_ to search for something related. There are literally _dozens_ of questions here that answer what you need.

Comment: @Ambily Avoid starting `id` Name as number.

Comment: @Ambily Post you HTML code of your form

Answer (score 0):

First cleanup your code.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="myMethod()">Submit</button>
```

**JS:**

```
myMethod = function () {
    if (!this.form.admin.checked && !this.form.security.checked && !this.form.security1.checked) {
        document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML = 'Make atleast one selection';

    } else if (this.form.admin.checked && this.form.security.checked && this.form.security1.checked == 1) {
        alert('security32 and admin and security64');
    } else if (this.form.security.checked && this.form.security1.checked == 1) {
        alert('security64 and security32');
    } else if (this.form.admin.checked && this.form.security.checked == 1) {
        alert('security32 and admin');
    } else if (this.form.admin.checked && this.form.security1.checked == 1) {
        alert('security64 and admin');
    } else if (this.form.admin.checked == 1) {
        alert('admin is checked');
    } else if (this.form.security.checked == 1) {
        alert('security 32 is checked');
    } else if (this.form.security1.checked == 1) {
        alert('security64 is checked');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should clean up your code by defining a function and then calling it from the button (like you did with the radio buttons) rather than sticking that long routine directly in the markup. You'll thank yourself down the road when you have to revisit this code to update it.

The overall problem is how you're referencing the checkboxes. You have `this.form.admin` and it should be `this.document.form[0].admin`. In context, the `this` keyword is the `window` object, so you have to specify `.document` to get to the document and then access the `forms` array where your form is presumably the first element (`forms[0]`). Once you've referenced the form correctly, you can then access your checkboxes by name (`.admin`, `.security`, `.security1`).

Also, as an aside, not that it matters in this case (since you're not using the `id` attributes), but per spec [`id` attributes **must** begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8VU7L/2/**

That said, you should probably access your inputs by `id` instead of DOM navigation to the `form` element. It's less fragile, more precise, and easier to read.

As another aside, you may want to read [Best Practice: Access form elements by HTML id or name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute).

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8VU7L/**

Finally, it may make your code more readable to use a bitfield (or rather, the JavaScript equivalent) for this kind of selection. In addition to readability, it's a snap to swap out messages for URLs using this technique.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8VU7L/1/**