# What is the difference between using document.getElementByID and document.form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to teach myself javascript through simple programming ideas. I tasked myself to make a way to calculate two numbers and provide a total of the results by option of using any of the four available operators. It's sort of a very simple calculator, to get to the point. I don't think I need to copy my html code - so I just posted my javascript.

Since I am new to programming in general and javascript, I looked around the web and found some code pointers.

```
<script>
function add() {
        var entry1 = document.getElementById("entry1").value;
        var entry2 = document.getElementById("entry2").value;
        var sum = Number(entry1)+Number(entry2);
        document.getElementById("results").value=sum    
 }

function sub() {
        var entry1 = document.form.entry1.value;
        var entry2 = document.form.entry2.value;
        var sum = Number(entry1)-Number(entry2);
        document.form.results.value=sum    
}

function multi() {
        var entry1 = document.form.entry1.value;
        var entry2 = document.form.entry2.value;
        var sum = Number(entry1)*Number(entry2);
        document.getElementById("results").value=sum    
}

function div() {
        var entry1 = document.form.entry1.value;
        var entry2 = document.form.entry2.value;
        var sum = Number(entry1)/Number(entry2);
        document.getElementById("results").value=sum    
}
</script>
```

I think this gives you insight into what I am playing around with. I thought it was interesting I found a way to get around using `document.getElementByID`, but I guess what I am trying to understand is how you can using both ways...the `document.form...` and `document.getElementById`.

Using "document.getElementById" will search the whole DOM looking for "entry1." "Form" in "document.form" refers to the form that encapsulates the whole contents in the `<body>` tag. As a theory, I did a `<div name="blah">` tag in front of `<form name="form">` to see if it would use "blah" if I changed `document.form` to `document.blah`...it broke. Same thing happened when I tried `document.blah.form.entry1`....). I think you can see what I am getting at.

I am just curious as to why `document.form.entry1.value;` works like `document.getElementById("entry1").value;`?

Comment: Using document.getElementById you are retrieving a specific element with the specified ID on the page. IDs should be unique to each element on a page. when using `document.form.` you are 'filtering down your selection. `document` refers to the webpage document, `form` retrieves any forms on the page (there may be more than 1), then `entry1` will retrieve the element with that id within the `document.form`.

Comment: Should be `document.forms` if you trying to get collection of form elements in the document. It seems, you add id or name to your form element as `form`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice: Access form elements by HTML id or name attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned,`document.getElementById` is to be used to select a specific element regardless of what it is. `document.forms` is to be used to specifically target forms and their elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think `document.form` points the specific form named or id'ed as the identifier "form" like `<form name="form" id="form">`.
Please check the syntax `document.forms` instead of `document.<an_identifier>` carefully.
`document.<an_identifier>` may be a dialect of IE.

Answer (score -1):

it's just a kind of syntactic sugar as for me.

Where have you found that "funny" sample? Let me refactor it a bit. hope it will help you better understand to main idea.

```
<script>



function add(a,b) {
       return Number(a) + Number(b);
 }

function sub(a,b) {
         return Number(a) - Number(b);
}

function multi(a,b) {
        return Number(a) * Number(b);
}

function div(a,b) {
        return Number(a) / Number(b);
}

function main () { //as an entry point;
  var entry1 = document.getElementById('entry1').value,
      entry2 = document.getElementById('entry2').value;
      $results =  document.getElementById("results");

  $results.value = add (entry1, entry2);
  //$results.value = sub (entry1, entry2);
  //$results.value = multi (entry1, entry2);
  //$results.value = div (entry1, entry2);
}
</script>
```

btw: even functions are redundant, but OK I left them as is.

enjoy to JS world

Comment: What about OP question: "What is the difference between using document.getElementByID and document.form?"