# Jscript : Function not working

Tags: javascript

I make a function to validate some required field on a form . But the function is not functioning , i dont know what is wrong please help me out .

**SCRIPT:**

```
 function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["function_search_form"]["id"].value;
    var y=document.forms["function_search_form"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("ID must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (y==null || y=="")
      {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
```

**FORM :**

```
<p><a href="borang_pencarikerja.php">Tambah Pencari Kerja Baru</a>&nbsp;<a href="borang_pencarikerja.php"><img src="images/add_16.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" align="absbottom" /></a></p>
<form action="simpan_jobseeker.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="function_search_form" id="function_search_form" class="search_form" onsubmit="validate()">

<td colspan="2"><strong>ID</strong>
<input type="text" name="id" id="txt_no_kp" value="<?php echo $no_kp; ?>" />
<div id="autocomplete_no_kp" class="autocomplete"></div></td>

<td colspan="2"><strong>Name</strong>
<div id="div_nama"><input name="name" type="text" id="txt_nama" size="40" /></div></td>
```

Comment: Whenever you post this kind of question it will be better if you refer a `jsfiddle` for quick and correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var x=document.forms["function_search_form"]["id"].value;
> var y=document.forms["function_search_form"]["name"].value
> ```

This does get the `.id` and `.name` properties of your `<form>`, which both are the string `"function_search_form"` - which does not have a `.value` property. Instead, either get the inputs [by ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
var x=document.getElementById("txt_no_kp").value;
var y=document.getElementById("txt_nama").value;
```

or by their name in the [`.elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements):

```
var x=document.forms["function_search_form"].elements["id"].value;
var y=document.forms["function_search_form"].elements["name"].value;
```

See also [Best Practice: Access form elements by HTML id or name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById("id").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("txt_nama").value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("ID must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (y==null || y=="")
      {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this code you were missing to close form tag and also you were calling wrong function name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["function_search_form"]["id"].value;
    var y=document.forms["function_search_form"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("ID must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (y==null || y=="")
      {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
</script>

<p><a href="borang_pencarikerja.php">Tambah Pencari Kerja Baru</a>&nbsp;<a href="borang_pencarikerja.php"><img src="images/add_16.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" align="absbottom" /></a></p>
<form action="simpan_jobseeker.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="function_search_form" id="function_search_form" class="search_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<td colspan="2"><strong>ID</strong>
<input type="text" name="id" id="txt_no_kp" value="<?php //echo $no_kp; ?>" />
<div id="autocomplete_no_kp" class="autocomplete"></div></td>

<td colspan="2"><strong>Name</strong>
<div id="div_nama"><input name="name" type="text" id="txt_nama" size="40" /></div></td>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```