# Slideshow using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, slideshow

I have been trying to create a slideshow using PHP and JavaScript mainly. However, for some reason there is no response after I click `>>` or `<<` to move to the next or previous slide.

The PHP script is mainly used to grab images from a folder and form them into an array. Then I use JavaScript within this PHP via `echo` to transform the PHP-array into a JavaScript-array.

I used [this website](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/preloadslide.htm) as a tutorial.

Thanks for your help!

```
<?php
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
//Header("content-type: text/javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname='C:\Apache\htdocs\Psych211LifespanDevchpt1') {
    echo "in return images";
    $files = array();
    $curimage = 0;

    if ($handles = opendir($dirname)) {
        echo "in handles";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handles))) {
            echo "in while";
            $path_info = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $extensions = pathinfo($path_info, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            echo $extensions;
            if ($extensions=='png')
            //if(eregi($pattern, $file)) { //if this file is a valid image
                //Output it as a JavaScript array element
                //$files->append($file);
                $files[$curimage] = $file;
                array_push($files,$file);
                //echo $files[$curimage];
                // 'Slides['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
                //echo $curimage;
                $curimage++;
            //}
        }
        echo $curimage;
        echo count($files);
        closedir($handle);
    }
    echo '<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var Slides = [];
    Slides = '.json_encode($files).'; document.write(Slides.length);
    function CacheImage(ImageSource) { // TURNS THE STRING INTO AN IMAGE OBJECT
        var ImageObject = new Image();
        ImageObject.src = ImageSource;
        return ImageObject;
    }

    function ShowSlide(Direction) {
       if (SlideReady) {
          NextSlide = CurrentSlide + Direction;
          // THIS WILL DISABLE THE BUTTONS (IE-ONLY)
          document.SlideShow.Previous.disabled = (NextSlide == 0);
          document.SlideShow.Next.disabled = (NextSlide == 
    (Slides.length-1));    
     if ((NextSlide >= 0) && (NextSlide < Slides.length)) {
                document.images["Screen"].src = Slides[NextSlide].src;
                CurrentSlide = NextSlide++;
                Message = "Picture " + (CurrentSlide+1) + "of " + 
    Slides.length;
                self.defaultStatus = Message;
                if (Direction == 1) CacheNextSlide();
          }
          return true;
       }
    }

    function Download() {
       if (Slides[NextSlide].complete) {
          SlideReady = true;
          self.defaultStatus = Message;
       }
       else setTimeout("Download()", 100); // CHECKS DOWNLOAD STATUS EVERY 100 MS
       return true;
    }

    function CacheNextSlide() {
       if ((NextSlide < Slides.length) && (typeof Slides[NextSlide] == 
    "string"))
    { // ONLY CACHES THE IMAGES ONCE
          SlideReady = false;
          self.defaultStatus = "Downloading next picture...";
          Slides[NextSlide] = CacheImage(Slides[NextSlide]);
          Download();
       }
       return true;
    }

    function StartSlideShow() {
       CurrentSlide = -1;
       Slides[0] = CacheImage(Slides[0]);
       var SlideReady = true;
       ShowSlide(1);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="StartSlideShow()"> 
<form name="SlideShow"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td colspan=2><img src="Psych211LifespanDevchpt1/slide-1.png" name="Screen" width=108 height=135></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td><input type="button" name="Previous" value=" << " onClick="ShowSlide(-1)"></td> 
<td align="right"><input type="button" name="Next" value=" >> " onClick="ShowSlide(1)"></td> 
</table> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>';

//return($files);


    }

    //echo 'var Slides=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
    returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
    ?>
```

Comment: You have `<input type="button" name="Previous" value=" << " onClick="doPrevious()">`/`<input type="button" name="Next"
value=" >> " onClick="doNext()">`. I don't see a `function doPrevious()` or `function doNext()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: looking at your linked tutorial, `onClick="doPrevious()"` should be `onClick="ShowSlide(-1)"` and `onClick="doNext()"` should be `onClick="ShowSlide(1)"`

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion, I copied and pasted the wrong part. It is supposed to be  `<body onLoad="StartSlideShow()">
<form name="SlideShow">
 <table>
<tr>
   <td colspan=2><img src="Psych211LifespanDevchpt1/slide-1.png" name="Screen" width=108 height=135></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="button" name="Previous" 
value=" << "
onClick="ShowSlide(-1)"></td>
   <td align="right"><input type="button" name="Next"
value=" >> " onClick="ShowSlide(1)"></td>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: update your question with this code.

Comment: @Sean I just updated the change with the code provided, hopefully this will clear my question a bit. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked your browser console to see if there are any error/syntax messages? have you checked the html source code to see what `Slides` looks like?

Comment: @Sean, there is no error messages showing, there would just simply be no response after I clicked the ">>" button. The Slides is an array in javascript that contains all the .png files. I have checked its information and am pretty sure it's not empty.

Comment: [Avoid using `document.write`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=1082s), use `console.log` for debugging instead. Any tutorials that tell you to use `document.write` are over a decade out of date and shouldn't be trusted. You also have a lot of variables that are capitalized. It is valid code, but in JS it has become a [convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) that only constructor functions be capitalized, other variables should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Also, don't use strings with `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`), they expect a function as their first parameter. If you instead give it a string, the string is implicitly `eval`ed. Instead of `setTimeout("Download()", 100);` you just need to do `setTimeout(Download, 100);`. It is shorter and will run faster, as well as avoiding potential XSS bugs being introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your functions use an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) variable name `SlideReady`. In
`StartSlideShow` you use `var SlideReady = true;` to try and set it. Because
you prefaced it with `var` you are setting a local variable that is also named
`SlideReady`, not the global variable that other functions have access to, so
the global `SlideReady` remains `undefined`.

So when `StartSlideShow` calls `ShowSlide`, the line

```
if (SlideReady) {
```

is interpreted as

```
if (false) {
```

because the global `SlideReady` is `undefined`, which is a [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) value. A falsy value is coerced to `false` inside the `if` statement, so the code inside of the `if` block never runs and the slide never changes.

Using a linter like [jsHint](http://jshint.com/) or the even stricter [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will help you avoid these kinds of errors.  Running all your code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) would also have made this kind of error more apparent. There are a number of other implicit globals in this code (`NextSlide`,  `CurrentSlide`, `Message`). Implicit globals can cause errors like this or even more insidious ones.

### Other things that could be improved

[window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) isn't commonly used. In particular the way this code uses it as a bare `self` without prefacing it with `window` could cause headaches. Many people [use a variable named `self` to store a reference to `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this) in situations where they need to access a `this` object of an outer function from inside another function using [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). Using `self` to refer to `window.self` will likely cause confusion for anyone reading code that uses it. (It did for me, it has been so long since I have seen a reference to `window.self` I forgot it existed!)

[`window.defaultStatus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/defaultStatus) has been obsolete for a long time, most browsers don't even have a status bar anymore; no one will see the messages that are being posted there.

This code has a lot of variable names that are capitalized. It is valid code and will run, but in JavaScript it has become a convention that only [constructor functions](http://helephant.com/2008/09/14/constructor-functions/) be capitalized. In simplest of terms, a constructor function is a function that needs to be called with the `new` keyword. If someone in the future (including you) works on the code, the function name being capitalized is a reminder that you need to use the `new` keyword before it. Linters also use this convention to automatically spot missing `new`s for you.

Accessing form elements via `document.formname.elementName` and images via `document.images` are very outdated techniques. Using `document.formName.elementName` can also [cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711843/778975) if a form element has the same name as a property of the form. Instead giving each button an `id`and accessing it via [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). In fact, you don't even need to use a form and buttons, it is easy to style a `div` or a `span` element to look like a button.

Using `onclick` is a dated way of attaching events, especially embedding it in the `onclick` in your HTML. It is less [obtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

[For a number of reasons](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) many people writing modern JavaScript prefer to use [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) to define `function`s instead of [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). Function declarations can cause some puzzling bugs, whereas a function expression stored in a variable behaves more predictably.

Global variables are bad and can often lead to all sorts of weird bugs, but often different parts of your code need access to common variables. You can allow this without creating globals by wrapping your code in an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (sometimes also called a self-invoking function).

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var shared = true,
    foo = function () {
      // has access to shared
    },
    bar = function () {
      // also has access to shared
    };
// you can access shared here
}());
// you can't access shared here because it is not a global
```

I personally don't feel it is necessary or worth it to preload the images. Most people will have a reasonably fast connection and if the images are encoded properly they will load in progressively and will be viewable in some state much quicker than with this code that won't display the image until it is fully loaded. Loading the next image before the user requests it also wastes their bandwidth which could be important if they are on mobile.

If you think that preloading the images is important, instead of using an overly complex system that won't display the next picture until it is fully downloaded, I would just preload them all at the beginning:

```
Slides.forEach(function (url) {
  (new Image()).src = url;
});
```

This will download each image and store it in the browsers cache instead of keeping it in memory in an array like the code you posted does.

### Modernizing the code

A more modern version of the JavaScript code from that tutorial might look more like this:

```
<img id="slide"></td>
<div class="slide-controls">
  <span class="button" id="prev-slide">&laquo;</span>
  <span class="button" id="next-slide">&raquo;</span>
</div>

<script>
  (function () {
    'use strict';
    var slides = [
        'http://www.placecage.com/300/200',
        'http://www.placecage.com/g/300/200',
        'http://www.placecage.com/c/300/200',
        'http://www.placecage.com/gif/300/200'
      ],
      currentSlide = 0,
      doc = document,
      elSlide = doc.getElementById('slide'),
      elPrev = doc.getElementById('prev-slide'),
      elNext = doc.getElementById('next-slide'),

      showSlide = function (index) {
        if (index > -1 && index < slides.length) {
          currentSlide = index;
          elPrev.classList.remove('disabled');
          elNext.classList.remove('disabled');
          if (index === 0) {
            elPrev.classList.add('disabled');
          } else if (index === slides.length - 1) {
            elNext.classList.add('disabled');
          }
          elSlide.src = slides[index];
          elSlide.title = 'Picture ' + (index + 1) + 'of ' + slides.length;
        }
      },
      changeSlide = function (step) {
          var index = currentSlide + step;
          showSlide(index);
      },
      prevSlide = changeSlide.bind(null, -1),
      nextSlide = changeSlide.bind(null, 1);

    elPrev.addEventListener('click', prevSlide, false);
    elNext.addEventListener('click', nextSlide, false);

    showSlide(0);
  }());
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/fpsop1y2/)

There is no need to use the `docuemnt` [`load` event (aka `onLoad`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load), the elements are defined in the markup above the JavaScript code and will be available when the JavaScript code runs.

Instead of using `defaultStatus`, I am putting the status message in the `title` attribute on the image, it should show up as a tool-tip in most browsers if the user mouses-over the image. You could also output the message to another `<div>` if you want it to be visible without a mouse-over.

I used [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create the event hanlders `prevSlide` and `nextSlide`.

The lines

```
  prevSlide = changeSlide.bind(null, -1),
  nextSlide = changeSlide.bind(null, 1);
```

are effectively equal to

```
  prevSlide = function () {
    changeSlide(-1);
  },
  nextSlide = function () {
    changeSlide(1);
  };
```

Since I separated the `changeSlide` logic from the actual display of the image and `showSlide` takes an index instead of how many forward or back to go, it would be easy to make a function that jumps to the first or the last slide too:

```
  var firstSlide = showSlide.bind(null, 0),
    lastSlide = showSlide.bind(null, slides.length - 1);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/w4kpze1n/)

### Other resources

Here are a few resources related to the techniques I used.

- [Crockford on JavaScript - Section 8: Programming Style & Your Brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY) Is particularly applicable to some of the stuff I discussed, [the whole series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxAXlJEmNMg&list=PL7664379246A246CB) is worth watching. Also, reading his book "JavaScript: The good parts" helps explain the reasons for a lot of this stuff.
- The Elements of JavaScript Style [part one](http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html), [part two](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html)
- [A good description of function declaration vs function expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22173438/778975)
- [Namespaces, Closures, Self-Invoking Functions, and much, much more...](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/advanced-javascript/)
- [JavaScript and HTML Script Tags](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)
- [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)