# How to get a form Id an attribute located in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form:

```
<form id="formId">
    <!-- some tags -->
    <div>
        <!-- some other divs or something else -->
            <input type="radio" onclick="handler(this) />
    </div>
</form>
```

Where the function handler looks like:

```
var handler = function(elem){
    init();
    var clicked = //here should be form id
    //other staff
};
```

How to get the id of the enclosed form? Assume that there's only one form on the web-page.

I'm looking for pure-js as well as jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure JS solution:

```js
var handler = function(elem) {
  // init();
  var clicked = elem.form.getAttribute('id');

  alert(clicked);
};
```

```html
<form id="formId">
  <!-- some tags -->
  <div>
    <!-- some other divs or something else -->
    <input type="radio" onclick="handler(this)" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

1) create the jquery object for elem.

2) Traverse to form element using `.closest('form')`

3) Use `.attr('id')` to get the id

```
$(elem).closest('form').attr('id');//will return "formId" in defined click handler
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/onxegjgq/)**

Comment: BTW, the pure JS example from another answer works just fine.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar you know you can stick that demo into your answer, right?

Comment: I meant embedded in the answer, not linked in it. But to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

Each `<input>` element in a form has a [`.form` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-form) that contains the `<form>` element they reside in; the `.id` is a property on any element.

```js
var handler = function(elem) {
  var clicked = elem.form.id;

  alert(clicked);
};
```

```html
<form id="formId">
    <!-- some tags -->
    <div>
        <!-- some other divs or something else -->
            <input type="radio" onclick="handler(this)" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: exactly why you should explicitly state your intention by using ``.getAttribute()``

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I would argue that you shouldn't have input elements with names that clash with standard element properties such as id.

Comment: And I would argue that you shouldn't use [property names that have undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435525/best-practice-access-form-elements-by-html-id-or-name-attribute)

Comment: The [`.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) property is pretty well established; it's just that for forms specifically (but maybe not exclusively) this property can be clobbered by individual input elements.

Answer (score 0):

you could make realy messy code like this.

```
var handler = function(elem){
    init();
    var searching = true;
    var tempElem = elem;
    while(searching)
    {
        //added check to make sure there is a parentNode as suggested by @Patrick Roberts
        tempElem = tempElem.parentNode || false;
        if(tempElem)
        {
            //added to lower case as corrected by @Patrick Roberts
            if(tempElem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "form")conversion
                searching = false;
        }
        else
            searching = false;//EDIT: if there is no form node then it will also stop searching
    }
    formElem = tempElem || {"id" :"no form found"};
    var clicked = formElem.id;//here should be form id
    //other staff
};
```

basically make a while loop to keep going up the chain of elements till you find a form element

Comment: ``if (tempElem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "form")``. [Node.nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) references [Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) which is uppercase in HTML, and only lowercase in X(HT)ML.

Comment: Also, if you reach the top without finding a form element, you'll get a ``ReferenceError`` before your ``while`` loop terminates.

Comment: Your corrected code will now never terminate once ``tempElem`` is false. ``searching`` is never set to false in that case.

Comment: i see. will add an else