# simple validation resists to validate textarea

Tags: javascript, html

the validation is working on the input fields, but it resists to do so on the textarea. Why? When i log the length of the textarea to the console, it says that document.guest is undefined... but in my opinion this is obviously not the case, because its working on the input fields.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function fcheck() {
    if (document.guest.name.value.length < 1) {
      alert("Du musst einen Namen eingeben!");
      return false;
    }
    if (document.guest.email.value.length < 1) {
      alert("Du musst eine Email eingeben!");
      return false;
    }
    if (document.guest.message.value.length < 1) {
      alert("Du musst eine Nachricht eingeben!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<div id="test2" class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <form action="addcomment.php" method="post" name="guest" onSubmit="return fcheck();">

        <div class="textform">
            <p>Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="textform">
            <p>E-Mail:
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control"/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="textform">
            <p>Nachricht(Maximal 300 Zeichen):</p>
            <textarea cols="50" name="message" rows="10" class="form-control status-box" maxlength="300"> </textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <p class="counter">300</p>
        </div>

        <div id="textarea" class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Nachricht abschicken" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not related i think, but you should now use id="textarea" this way. Each id must be unique (and relevant).

Comment: Youre right, thx. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to prevent `form` default action using `preventDefault`. So replace this line of code in html: (for more info : [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)
)

```
onSubmit="return fcheck();"
```

with :

```
onSubmit="event.preventDefault(); fcheck();"
```

second, in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fcheck() {
        if (document.forms.guest.name.value.trim().length < 1) {
            alert("Du musst einen Namen eingeben!");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.forms.guest.email.value.trim().length < 1) {
            alert("Du musst eine Email eingeben!");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.forms.guest.message.value.trim().length < 1) {
            alert("Du musst eine Nachricht eingeben!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Now with event.preventDefault(); it does not submit the form. @Mehran Torki

Comment: @Pingbeat I've just edited the code. It's working fine in my browser.

Comment: This answer should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You should write :

```
document.forms.guest
```

Instead of :

```
document.guest
```

You should also have a peek on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435762/4375327).

EDIT : in fact, your textarea has a length of "1" ! See this [edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h03osaws/3/). It's due to the space character. Remove it and it will works.

Comment: Done that, sadly nuttin changed. :( Both of the input fields still do the alert, the textarea does not. @Amessihel

Comment: @Pingbeat, I just found your issue. Read the update. :)

Comment: so `document.forms.guest.message.value.trim().length` works well.

Comment: @MehranTorki indeed, and it's a better solution also.

Comment: Where is this space char you are speaking of? I dunno what you mean :O

Answer (score 1):

textareas dont show on `document.form`, you can access it like so:-

```
document.guest.elements["message"].value
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. But is there a reason I cant handle the textarea as I handled the inputs?