# In javascript is this a valid construct?: document.name.name.value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here's the form:

```
<form name=fname ...
   <input name=iname value="" ...
```

This javascript function obtains the value of the input with:

```
var val = document.fname.iname.value;
```

Is that legit?  I thought you had to do this with `getElementsByName`.  It works, it's just I've never seen anyone do it that way. Is this one of those things that just happens to work... for now?

Comment: yes you can do this with the name attribute.

Comment: `document.forms.fname.elements.iname.value` is the better style.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/1048572) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2435525/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### UPDATE

According to WHATWG [6.2.4 Named access on the Window object](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

> The Window object supports named properties. The supported property names of a Window object window at any moment consist of the following,...for all `applet`, `embed`, `form`, `frameset`, `img`, and `object` elements...

---

According to W3C DOM 2 HTML Specification [2.7.2.1 HTMLAllCollection](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#htmlallcollection)

> The following elements name attribute can be referenced as a property of the document object:
> `anchor`, `applet`, `button`, `form`, `frame`, `iframe`, `img`, `input`, `map`, `meta`, `object`, `param`, `select`, and `textarea`

---

This referencing approach is standard, but it's use is generally discouraged. A few reasons to avoid directly referencing DOM property or window object by `name` attributes are: variable shadowing, inadvertently scoping to the window object, major browser inconsistencies, etc. For details on why it should be avoided, read [this section](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/references.php#avoid) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381766/2813224).

This Snippet shows a stable and standard way of using form names as a reference [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) and the  referencing form names previously mentioned as well.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var val1 = document.forms.fname.elements.iname.value;

console.log(val1);

var val2 = fname.iname.value;

console.log(val2);
```

```html
<form name='fname'>
   <input name='iname' value="42">
</form>
```

Comment: They're not asking about the `document forms` collection but rather about accessing forms by name directly on the `document` object.

Comment: This Snippet shows the better way of using form names as a reference and the referencing previously mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure this is non-standard?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It seems the .name.name. thing is a collections hack.  I wonder if .name.name. would work elsewhere on elements just hanging out in space somewhere.  Thanks.  -3 is kinda heavy.   Here's a point.

Comment: @zer00ne: The reason I ask is that in the WHATWG, I see a reference to a getter on the `documents` object, as... `getter object (DOMString name);
` Trying to dig up more info.

Comment: AFAIK this involves form elements only. There is `window.frames.name` for referencing an iframe's window object but it's not a hack.

Comment: @squint - You are quite correct. It's perfectly standard. It's described under section [3.1.3 DOM tree accessors](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors) of the HTML5 spec. Scroll down to the part that starts "The Document interface supports named properties. "

Comment: @Alohci: Ah, thanks. Looks like it's in the previous published version too, so it's definitely spec'd. Don't know if I'd personally use it, but good to know either way.

Comment: @squint Found the specs as well, updated accordingly. It's standard albeit a mess.

Comment: For `val2`, you can remove the `document.` prefix.