# Difference between form id and form name used in html

Tags: html, coding-style

I want to know the exact difference between form id and form name used in html.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-tag-attributes-html

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean on the form's elements: e.g. button/input/select & textarea elements?

If so, the name attribute is what is sent when the form is submitted.  The id attribute uniquely identifies any element on the page.

The best example I can think of is radio buttons.

Each radio button belongs to a set, and the set has a name.  However you may want to link to a particular button by id.

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="c1" value="r"/><label for="c1">Red</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="c2" value="y"/><label for="c2">Yellow</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="c3" value="b"/><label for="c3">Blue</label>
```

When the form is submitted, only the selected option is sent: (e.g. Yellow)

```
?color=y
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

You can have a form for email... and have many of them (from a while loop)...
They are all email forms (the same) but uniquely identified by id=each user displayed on the page.

```
<form name="email" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" method=...
```