# HTML Forms - Are name and id required?

Tags: html, forms, post

Why do I need the **name** and **id** attributes for `<input>` form elements?

Which is used for POST data sending and which can I exclude?

Comment: Related: *[Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`name` is used by the server-side. This is *necessary* if you plan to process the field. `id` is only so `label` elements, when clicked and accessed by screen-readers, can trigger/invoke the form controls (inputs and selects).

```
<form method=POST action="form-processor.php">
    <input name=first_name value=john>
</form>
```

results in

```
$_POST = array('first_name' => 'john');
```

If the method is `GET`, it's appended to the query string:

`http://site-name.com/form-handler.php?first_name=john`

It's popular for query string appending with hidden inputs:

`<input type="hidden" name="q" value="1">`

Answer (score 9):

An *id* isn't required. *Name* isn't mandatory either, but the browser will not sent the `<input>`'s data without it. This is the same for [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Answer (score 4):

**name** is used for POST and GET.

**id** is used for styling.

**class** is used for applying the same style to a bunch of elements that are of the same "class".

That's how I memorize them.

Comment: id is also used to associate a <label> with an <input>, e.g. <label for="foobar">Foobar</label> <input id="foobar">.

Comment: Thanks Olly, this is much better than wrapping the <input> with the <label> (Yikes!)

Comment: Are there any accessibility benefits of using a name property?

Comment: id is NOT used for styling. Classes are for styling.

Answer (score 3):

`name` is the attribute that determines the "variable name" when doing a post. `id` is used for JavaScript purposes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML5 quote**

*[Naming form controls: the name attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-name)* confirms that it is not mandatory:

> The name content attribute gives the name of the form control, as used in form submission and in the form element's elements object. If the attribute is specified, its value must not be the empty string or isindex.

**What happens if it is not specified?**

In Chromium 75 where I [tested with `nc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests/52351480#52351480), it just does not get sent:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Min sane</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8000" method="post">
            <p><input type="text" name="key" value="default value"></p>
            <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

sends:

```
key=default+value
```

but without `name` it simply doesn't.

Both pass [the HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) however.

**Why would you want an `input` without `name`?**

JavaScript can still access the value and do something with it.

Comment: Can you replace the rhetorical question with a statement? This is not a forum.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather keep them as is.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is needed for [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)... but not `id`... `id` is used for client-side processing.

Answer (score 0):

*Name* is required so that you can post or get the values in the next page. *Id* is required for you to do manipulations with CSS and stuff like that. It is also possible only with the name. So *Name* is more important. Giving an *id* makes it look standardised.

Comment: Why does giving it an ID make it look 'standardized'? And you really should use 'necessary' instead of 'required'. Word choice is key in programming.

Comment: document.getElementsByName() can be used instead of document.getElementsById() for all client side operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that the name attribute *is required* if you're working with **radio elements**.

With the name attribute, the radios in a radio group will belong together. Example below:

```
<p>Colors</p>
<div>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="radio-red"><label for="radio-red">Red</label>
   <input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" id="radio-blue"><label for="radio-blue">Blue</label>
</div>

<p>Pets</p>
<div>
   <input type="radio" name="pets" value="cats" id="radio-cats"><label for="radio-cats">Cats</label>
   <input type="radio" name="pets" value="dogs" id="radio-dogs"><label for="radio-dogs">Dogs</label>
</div>
```

Link for you to play with: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-andreasson-jogmark/pen/PoQprja

Answer (score -1):

*name* is required, and *id* is not that important. However, *id* is used to associate labels to common form input fields like radio button, textboxes, etc.

Comment: The name attribute is *not* required.

Comment: @animuson, while I agree with you, technically, I'd argue that, if you want to do something with the entered data, it's kind of essential to have a `name` attribute.

Comment: @ricebowl: You're basically saying it is necessary in order to perform certain functions, but there are still plenty of uses for an input field where a name attribute would not be needed.

Comment: @animuson: true, but if you need the data in the field to be posted to the server (for processing), the name attribute is required.

Comment: There is still a difference between requirement and necessity. If you were writing an instruction manual, you would say that you "need to define a name attribute if you are planning to post the data." You don't say a name attribute is required because that gives them the false assumption that they must *always* define a name attribute.

Comment: @animuson, I accept that there are valid uses for a name-less input, but I can't think what they would be; which is the position from which I wrote my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidThomas. For anyone coming late to this, checkboxes and radio buttons can be used via CSS or JavaScript to control what is subsequently visible, which can unclutter a page and reduce the amount of tabbing for those using a keyboard to navigate. Note that Chromium-based browsers will [only] issue a warning if they appear within a form without either a `name` or `id`, but Firefox correctly doesn't. Such usage will likely not need to send any data with the form.

Comment: @animuson. Required is not necessarily so absolute, since it can also have a condition associated with it, as in "a name attribute is required for a control if wanting its value attribute submitted with the form".

Answer (score -1):

Neither `name` nor `id` need to be specified for form elements outside of a `form`. Chromium-based browsers will issue a warning stating `A form field element should have an id or name attribute` if such elements are included in a form, but Firefox does not. It is probably only a warning to notify page designers that they may have forgotten the attributes, but it gives the impression that it is bad practice, especially if many of them are shown.

There are valid uses for form controls without such attributes. For example, checkboxes and radio buttons can be used via CSS or JavaScript to control the visibility, using CSS `display`, of subsequent elements. This can unclutter a page and substantially reduce the amount of tabbing keyboard-bound users need to do, only clicking on the control to expose the hidden elements when required.

These controls would usually not have values that need to be sent with any enclosing form as the exposed controls would likely be doing that.

Such usage will not necessarily require `name` or `id` attributes, though `id` would be required if the controls have associated `label` elements which they are not a descendent of. Note that for CSS control of subsequent elements' visibility, the elements used in the CSS definitions must be a sibling of their associated `label`, as children of a `label` cannot be used in CSS to control anything about siblings of that `label` or its descendants.

The `for` attribute for a `label` to be associated with a control that is not a descendant must have that control's `id` as its value for them to be linked.