# Should images have a "name" attribute?

Tags: html

I notice Dreamweaver creates a `name` attribute automatically with the same value as `id`, which I wouldn't have thought to do. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-tag-attributes-html) asking the difference between `name` and `id` attributes in HTML, but what about where it applies to images?

Comment: One tip: always clean up the code Dreamweaver generates for you. Not only will your code look better afterwards, you should also learn something useful from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is an attribute included for scripting backwards compatibility and should be of no use today.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

> **`name = cdata [CI]`**
>   This attribute names the element so that it may be referred to from style sheets or scripts. *Note:* This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the `id` attribute to identify elements.

Answer (score 3):

Expando attributes won't hurt anything in any modern browser. It was officially supported in HTML 4.01, but removed in Strict XHTML:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/

Regardless, it is pretty much useless for anything. Dreamweaver has included it for as long as I can remember.

A validator will complain (legitimately so) if you add an unsupported attribute to a tag.

Comment: It *is* an official attribute, at least in HTML 4.

Comment: For information about standards, it's always best to go to the source. http://w3.org :)

Comment: HTML 4 didn't include it. HTML 4.01 did.  XHTML removed it. Note section C.8: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/. +1 for the standards recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Name is pretty much only useful for forms. You can use it as a way to add metadata to images, but there are more standard ways to do that these days.

Answer (score 0):

ID attribute should be used for now.

> The NAME attribute, added to IMG in
>   HTML 4.01, specifies a name for
>   referring to the image from a
>   client-side script. The ID attribute
>   provides the same functionality, but
>   old browsers such as Netscape 4.x only
>   support the NAME attribute.

Source: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/img.html