# Name vs Id attribute in HTML

Tags: html

Are there any advantages to using `<div id="here" ...` instead of `<div name="here" ...`?

Are they both referenced to as #here?

Comment: There is no `<div name="...">` in HTML.

Comment: Similar to http://goo.gl/Tj3mj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here are some differences between both:

1. *name* has never been a *div* element attribute.
2. *name* as used on the form controls (input, textarea, select, and button elements) is radically different from the *id* attribute on named elements. In this case, the name attribute relates to how data is labeled when sent to server, and multiple elements may share the same name.

   The id attribute on the other hand is for identifying one unique element for the purposes of scripting, styling, or addressing.
3. The use of the *name* attribute on other elements than form controls was in HTML 4.01 the same as that of *id*, but it allowed for a wider set of characters than the *id* attribute and wasn't controlled in quite the same way. Because of this ambiguity the [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) decided to deprecate/remove the *name* attribute on those elements in favor for the unambigous *id* attribute in XHTML.

   This is also connected to another detail of XML however - only one attribute of any element may be of the type *ID*, which would not be the case if they let *name* stay on the element, but corrected the ambiguity problems.
4. As the name attribute didn't work the same on those two sets of elements, it was best to remove one of them.

In short, for backwards compatibility, you should use the *name* and *id* attribute both, both set to the same value, for all elements except form controls if you use HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0 Transitional. If you use XHTML 1.0 Strict or later you should use only *id*. For form controls, you should use *name* for what you want the form to send to the server and for DOM 0 access, and only use *id* for styling, DOM1-3 access or addressing reasons

Answer (score 5):

It depends on where you are going to use them.

Usually, `id` of an element is unique while multiple elements can share the same `name`.

*Id* is referenced as `#here`, and *name* is referenced as `[name=here]`.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't talking about `class`

Comment: According to the standard, ID *must* be unique on the whole page. Name - which is not valid for all tags - does not necessarily need to be unique.

Comment: But `name` is also referenced as `#name`?

Comment: In CSS (or javascript using CSS selectors), name is not referenced as #name. Class is referenced as .class. It sounds like you're getting this mixed up with the URL hash. If an element has name or id, then you can put #name at the end of the URL and it will scroll to that element on the page.

Answer (score 4):

They are not interchangeable, even if they sometimes appear to be.

*Name* should only exist on form input fields. It is what that tag will cause the browser to pass in the submission as the name of the field. As Tomalak noted in a comment, DIV actually does not have a *Name* attribute.

ID is the unique identifier for the DOM, to manipulate or refer to the tag; for example, in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The "id" attribute assigns an identifier to the associated element. This identifier must be unique in the document and can be used to refer to that element.

Check *[div element](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/div.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking about the input tag. It offers the *name* attribute to identify which input is what when the form is submitted.

*id* would be only used to style the input, whereas *name* would not.

Answer (score 0):

One thing of importance that hasn't been mentioned in the other answers is that a form with a *name* attribute gets added as a variable to the document object in JavaScript. Any form controls with a name inside that form are accessible as child objects on the form element.

So if, for example, you had some HTML like the following:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" type="text" />
</form>
```

You could access the form with `document.myForm` or access the input element with `document.myForm.myInput`.

See an example of this idea in action on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lromacy/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

1. the [*id* attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) is to be unique across the entirety of the HTML document, and
2. the [*name* attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) has no such requirement.

By convention, the *name* value is used with forms to help with the processing of forms, particularly with radio buttons. How you use the *name* attribute depends on your use case. If you need some other tag for your use case, you can of course create a new attribute and use that as you will; pick a name for your attribute that will likely be very unique!