# What do "id" and "name" do in a form?

Tags: html, forms

When you submit a form, does the form look for both "name" and "id" values? What does the "id" do other than styling it with CSS?

```
<select name="combobox" id="combobox">
   <option value="0">Inactive</option>
   <option value="1">Active</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here's an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487860/name-vs-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: [List of uses of the id attribute in HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags/13001519#13001519)

Comment: @jpaugh This specifically asks in the context of <form>, not the whole concept of id and name attributes and their usages.

Comment: Related: *[Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Name

The *name* attribute is needed for the database or other data destination to uniquely identify that piece of data.

When the form is submitted, most scripts use the *name* attribute to place the form data into a database or into an email that can be read by a person. Thus, if the <input> element is for the site visitor to enter their name into, then the name attribute would be name="name" or name="first-name", etc. ([source (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics#The_name_attribute)).

A control's "control name" is given by its name attribute. The scope of the name attribute for a control within a FORM element is the FORM element. [Source (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

#### Id

The id attribute has several roles in HTML:

- As a style sheet selector.
- As a target anchor for hypertext links.
- As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
- As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
- For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g., for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database, translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.) ([Source (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).)

Answer (score 1):

`name` indicates that key will be used to send the value.

`id` is typically used so that JavaScript can find the element.

For convenience, they may be the same, but not necessarily.

Comment: Re *"send the value"*: When the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

> When you submit a form, does the form look for both "name" and "id" values?

No, just the name attribute

> What does the "id" do other than styling it with CSS?

You can use the *id* to reference the element in the form elements collection.

Say we have a form element referenced by the variable `form`, you can access the element (form elements, input , selects, etc.) in the form. With *id*, say `combobox`, then you can access this element via `form['combobox']` or `form.combobox` . This is also true for the *name* attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/YQRtR/.

Comment: Re *"...reference the element in the form elements collection"*: In what context and from where? JavaScript / DOM? On the server? On the client? Can you clarify in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

`name` will appear in the query string, i.e.,

```
?name=value
```

So in your case:

```
?combobox=0 OR ?combobox=1
```

depending on the user's selection.

`id` is used by CSS to add styles, similar to `class` except a specific `id` can only be assigned to one DOM element. The `id` can also be used to manipulate the element on the DOM using JavaScript, as it allows the element to be identified.

Comment: What query string? In what context? For HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to *developer.mozilla.org* or *http://htmldog.com/* for details about HTML.

**id**

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

**name**

The *name* attribute specifies the name of a form.

The *name* attribute is used to reference elements in JavaScript code, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.