# Are there two ways to jump to a fragment identifier in HTML?

Tags: html, fragment-identifier

I always thought the standard way to specify a fragment identifier is by `<a name="foo"></a>`.

```
<a href="#foo">go to foo</a>

<a name="foo"></a>                        <!-- obsolete method, it seems -->
<p>some content under that anchor with name</p>
```

But it seems like this is the old way, and the new way is using an `id`, like this:

```
<a href="#bar">go to bar</a>

<p id="bar">some content under that p with id</p>
```

In fact, the W3C validator says that `name` is obsolete for the `<a>` element.  So are there 2 ways to jump to the fragment identifier but 1 of them is obsolete?  (And when did that happen?)

(there are other questions about the difference between `id` and `name`, but this one is about fragment identifier)

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487860/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/

Answer (score 8):

> So are there 2 ways to jump to the fragment identifier but 1 of them is obsolete?

There are two ways to identify a fragment.

(There are also two ways to jump to one, since you can do it with a URL or write a pile of JavaScript to scroll the page).

> And when did that happen?

`id` was introduced in 1996 when HTML 4 came out. It effectively obsoleted the `name` attribute for anchors.

`name` was made officially obsolete in HTML 5 in 2014 (or in Living HTML on some date that I'm not going to try to figure out).

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are two ways to jump to a fragment identifier and both aren't obsolete ( except `a` element).

That's rules applied to all HTML 5 elements other than `a` (because in `a` hasn't `name` attribute in HTML5).

**So shortly it's obsolete to idenfity `name` attribute as fragment idenitifier for `a` element as that's attribute depricated since HTML4.**

Flow of accessing `fragment` from [HTML5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid):

> - If there is an element in the DOM that has
>     an ID exactly equal to fragid, then the first such element in tree
>     order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> - If there is an a element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose
>     value is exactly equal to fragid, then the first such element in tree
>     order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> - Otherwise, there is no indicated part of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways of doing fragment identifiers work.

Using `id="fragment"` is the newer, recommended way of jumping to fragments in HTML. It was introduced with HTML4, and works basically everywhere (I just verified this with IE5).

`<a name="fragment">`, the older way, still works, but [is obsolete since HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name).

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I happened to have that in a Win2000 VM so I decided to go for it. I guess it also applies to later versions.

Answer (score 1):

> Answer to your question: Yes, There are two ways to identify a fragment and one is obsolete.

#### What is Fragment Identifiers ?

1. Fragment identifiers for text/plain.
2. URIs refer to a location in the same resource. This kind of URI starts with "#" followed by an anchor identifier (called the fragment identifier).

Fragment Identifier using JS like below.

```
location.replace('#middle');
```

Answer (score 1):

More information on the `name` attribute.

Basically, the `name` attribute has been deprecated (obsolete in HTML5-speak) for just about everything except for `form` elements. Forms retain them as the method of identifying data, and it is the `name` plus the `value` property which is sent back to the server. (The `id` in form elements is used for attaching `label` elements, and has nothing to do with the actual data).

There is a fundamental weakness in the `name` attribute, which the `id` attribute addresses: the `name` attribute is not required to be unique. This is OK for forms where you can have multiple elements with the same `name`, but unsuitable for the rest of the document where you are trying to uniquely identify an element.

The `id` attribute was specifically required to be unique, which makes it better for identifying a link target, among other things. CSS is pretty relaxed about applying styles to multiple elements with the same `id`, but JavaScript is more strict about this requirement. And, of course, you can’t have a practical link target if you can’t guarantee uniqueness.