# Do the id and name have to match inside form input tags?

Tags: html, input, tags, xhtml

I learned that [in XHTML 1.0 the name and id have to match](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/guidelines.html#C_8), as the fact that name it an attribute from HTML first, and they decide to use the id.

> In XML, URI-references [RFC2396] that end with fragment identifiers of the form "#foo" do not refer to elements with an attribute name="foo"; rather, they refer to elements with an attribute defined to be of type ID, e.g., the `id` attribute in HTML 4. Many existing HTML clients don't support the use of ID-type attributes in this way, so identical values may be supplied for both of these attributes to ensure maximum forward and backward compatibility (e.g., ...).

So what's considered legitimate today?

Are tags like `<br /> <!-- //--> <input />` still acceptable?

Comment: Not necessary to be same.

Comment: You misread the specification, it doesn't say that. It says that for backwards compatibility, on `<a>` elements (**not** `<input>` elements because they weren't used an anchors in pre-ID HTML) identical `name` and `id` attributes **may** be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `id` attribute is just a way to uniquely identify a html element. This id can be used in a lot of ways depending on how you are creating the html (raw html with css, react, ect).

The `name` attribute is usually used to identify data in the multipart-form-data of a http request.

You might also look here:

- [difference between id and name attributes in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)
- [name vs id attribute in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487860/name-vs-id-attribute-in-html?noredirect=1&lq=1)