# Entering data using VBA in to a HTML5 site

Tags: html, vba

Hi i need to enter a car reg into the below input box:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase car-registration__input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" 
data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" 
data-ng-keyup="inputChange=true; regnumberNotFound=false; carLookupButtonSubmitted=false" data-motor-regnumber="" 
data-msm-answer-store-key="" data-ng-required="true" 
data-msm-answer-store-action="{'regnumberUpdate': {'targets': [{}]}}" 
data-msm-error-tracking-view-change="" id="regnumber" name="regnumber" 
data-ng-model="regnumber" maxlength="10" data-msm-field-interaction-events="click" 
data-ng-change="returnedUserCheck()" required="required">
```

using the following i can enter the value but the box doesn't think that there is anything there and therefore wont validate and i have to manually click inot the text box:

```
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).innerText = Reg
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).setCapture
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Click
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).releaseCapture
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(7).Click
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar trouble with a form and I found this:

[VBA interaction with internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652890/vba-interaction-with-internet-explorer)

Which helped me solve the exact same type of problem!

The trick was to use

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long
```

At the top of the Module, then modify your code to the following:

```
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
HWNDSrc = ie.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Focus()
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Value = Reg + "." 'extra full stop will be removed on the next line
Application.SendKeys "{BS}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).innerText = Reg
```

With:

```
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).value = Reg
```

The `value` attribute specifies the value of an `<input>` element

> The value attribute is used differently for different input types:
>
> - For "`button`", "reset", and "submit" - it defines the text on the
>     button
> - For "text", "password", and "hidden" - it defines the initial
>     (default) value of the input field
> - For "checkbox", "radio", "image" -
>     it defines the value associated with the input (this is also the value
>     that is sent on submit)
>
> *Note: The value attribute cannot be used with `<input type="file">`*.

**Edit:**

It looks as if it's using angular to check the value has changed.
Specifically, this attribute on the input element:

```
data-ng-keyup="inputChange=true; regnumberNotFound=false; carLookupButtonSubmitted=false"
```

It appears that you would need to also trigger a `keyup` event, which will likely require something like the following:

```
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Focus()
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Value = Reg + "." 'extra full stop will be removed on the next line
SendKeys "{BS}"
```

However, SendKeys is usually frowned upon unless absolutely necessary.

It may be worth trying to "trick" the form to recognise the value change by forcing the `blur` event to occur.
This can be done by setting the focus to the input box, then setting the focus to another element, as follows:

```
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).Focus()
IE.document.all("regnumber")(1).innerText = Reg
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(7).Focus()
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(7).Click
```

I'd recommend trying this suggestion before going down the `SendKeys` route

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but alas I have the same issue, when i click the button it still thinks that the text box is empty.

Comment: Thanks, but these too don't fire the event correctly, I've tried shifting focus off and back on, I've tried to firing events and the only thing that works is a good old fashioned mouse click!