# Accessing form input by ID

Tags: php, forms

I know in PHP you have `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_REQUEST` to access form input through their names in the html tags. Is it possible to do the same for their ids? For example:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
</form>
```

In PHP:

```
$f_name = $_GET['firstname'];
```

Comment: Using Javascript, you can: `getElementById()` - but as far as I know, you can't get this information server-side.

Comment: Why not though? Aren't names and ids virtually the same thing?

Comment: @LeonHelmsley No, id's and names are not the same.

Comment: Same thing? Of course not. Names don't even need to be unique.

Comment: @LeonHelmsley ID's are used for CSS purposes (and Javascript) - PHP just doesn't transfer this information when a post is made.

Comment: I see; so ids are clientside and names are serverside. Thanks!

Comment: homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting a form, only the input fields with a `name` attribute are submitted. Just add a `name` attribute same as `id`, or do some JavaScript hack to populate `name` attributes on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this when submitting the form normally. You could however, use client-side JavaScript to construct the submission to the PHP script.

But this assumes you can modify the client-side page. If you can do that, you can also just add the correct names to the form fields.

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
</form>
```