# get value of input using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, html-input

I am trying to get value of input using js but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Alert doesn't work.

```
<body>
   <form name="inputform" id="form1" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get" style="visibility:hidden">
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" ></input>
      <input type="button" value="Gönder" onclick="CreateU()"></input>
   </form>
</body>
```

js file:

```
var xmail="";
CreateU = function(){
  var xx = "";
  xmail=document.getElementById('email').value;
  alert(xmail);
  xx= myAddress + xmail + ans + tf;
  window.location.assign(xx);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your email input doesn't have an ID:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` to your "Email" input: `<input type="text" name="email" id="email" ></input>`
Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/K8kp9/
Note that now you possibly see nothing because of `style="visibility:hidden"` at your `form` tag..
Have some reading: [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

email is a name, just change 'name' to 'id' ^^

Answer (score 0):

please set the id in email

```
 <body>
    <form name="inputform" id="form1"  action="html_form_action.asp" method="get"       style="visibility:hidden">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ></input>
    <input type="button" value="Gönder" onclick="CreateU()"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

use id attribute in the input to get the value by using document.getElementById().

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" ></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to mention `id='email'` in your `input` element.