# Inserting name into database?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to insert a PHP 5 form into a MySQL database?

```
<form  action="script.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />           
 </fieldset>
</form>​
```

Do I still have you use all of these?

```
$name= $_POST['name'];  
$name = stripslashes($name);  
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO names VALUES ('','$name')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

Because when I do this, the script only enters the ID, the name field remains empty..

EDIT: How to use PDO or mysqli in PHP 5 (by the latest standards)?

Comment: First do not use mysql_* as it is deprecated on PHP 5.5. You asked for the best way, use PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your name input to have the name attribute="name" ie.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

To fully address your answer.

- The mysql_* library is deprecated on the latest PHP's and SHOULD NOT be used. Use PDO or MySQLi instead. Thanks to Prix for pointing that out.
- You'll want to sanitize data that users give.  This question has been asked before and a good answer exists here: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
- The reason your _POST parameter was not doing anything on your name input was due to the fact that was mentioned above.

Comment: See also: [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1397592/2359271)

Comment: Nothing about mysqli or pdo?

Comment: Great that worked out well! Are the stripslashes($name) and mysql_real_escape_string($name) operations still needed in PHP 5?

Comment: The practice of sanitizing the data that your end-users put in is a good thing.  Those are valid methods to use, however, with regards to mysql_real_escape_string that function will be deprecated.  Read this for further information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attribut allows in html 5 to put a default value in an element of a form. This default value is remove when the element has focus. But in your case you have forget the attribut name. Try this:

```
<form  action="script.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />           
 </fieldset>
</form>​
```