# Transition when click on <a>

Tags: html, css

I know that the title isn't good, but I couldn't tell all the story in one short sentence. Sorry about that.
I created a *TERMS* page (how to use the site and stuff) and I added a little menu for all the parts on the page (such as contribute, law stuff, user respect and more).
So I did this such of thing:

```
<li> <a href="#contribute">CONTRIBUTE</a> </li>

--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff

<a name="contribute"></a>

--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
```

And I want when you click on the `CONTRIBUTE` link, there will be a transition like [WEEBLY](http://www.weebly.com/) did (click at the bottom of first section).

Comment: When you click on the CONTRIBUTE link, does it jump to the CONTRIBUTE section? Is it just the transition you're looking for?

Comment: yeah it jumps to the CONTRIBUTE section but it's a little ugly, I want to add a transition

Comment: If you google "Js scroll to id", there are lots of javascript solutions that are already out there. Try this one for starters: http://code-tricks.com/jquery-scroll-to-div/

Comment: And off-topic, but I would also consider changing your "name" property to be "id", as "name" is generally used for forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `'id'` attribute at the place of `'name'` attribute. as follows:

```
<li> <a href="#contribute">CONTRIBUTE</a> </li>

<p>--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff</p>

<a id="contribute"></a>

<p>--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li> <a href="#contribute">CONTRIBUTE</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#other">OTHER</a> </li>

--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff

<!--also <a id="contribute"></a>-->
<p id="contribute">
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
</p>
<!-- also <a id="other"></a>-->
<p id="other">
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff--stuff
</p>
```