# Dynamic (JS) Form Controls: How to read content?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have an ASP.NET form where I add content () dynamicly using Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#dynamicarea').append($('<input id="dyn1" type="text" value="awesome!">'));
```

On postback I tried to receive the content the following way:

```
protected void save_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
    // do fancy stuff
  }
}
```

But Request.Form.AllKeys do not seem to have the dynamically added input fields.

What is needed to access these fields from codebehind?

Comment: did you add your input tags in a form context addressed to self?

Comment: try adding name attribute? <input id="dyn1" name="dyn1" type="text" value="awesome!">

Comment: In addition to the Sherin Mathew comment you may be interested in reading the explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Comment: In Request.Form.AllKeys you will find html controls by `name` and server controls by `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not added the name attribute, the Request.Form.AllKeys will not contain the item.

Modify the script to include the name attribute as below.

```
$('#dynamicarea').append($('<input id="dyn1" name="dyn1" type="text" value="awesome!">'));
```