# Adding value to hidden input tag and submitting to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a test page that displays my POST data. I am trying to view the post that I just submitted but I am unable to see the added `payload` I added in my form.

HTML:

```
  <form id="test-form" action="/test/" method="post"> {# pass data to /test/ URL #}
    <div class="test-button-set">
      <button type="button" id="hdfs-test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg selected">HDFS</button>
      <button type="button" id="hive-test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE</button>
      <button type="button" id="hdfs-hive-test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH</button>
    </div>
    <button id="submit-test" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="payload">
  </form>
```

JS:

```
var testData = {
        "timestamp": "",
        "hive": 0,
        "hdfs": 0,
        "beacons":[]
    };

var testRun = document.getElementById("test-form");
    testRun.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        testData["timestamp"] = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(testData);
        var payload = document.getElementById("payload");
        payload.value = testData;
        $(this).trigger('submit', true);
    });
```

Currently, I cannot see the value I gave to `<input type="hidden" id="payload">` which makes me to believe that it is not getting posted.

Comment: Try Giving the input an attribute of name="payload".

Comment: if you are using php or something like in backend the for that you need name for your hidden field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the input a name:

```
<input type="hidden" id="payload" name="payload">
```

See this SO answer: [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Thanks this worked! But what I see is u'payload': `[u'[object Object]']` is there a way to display it?

Comment: What type of server is the target of the POST?  Maybe this is a separate SO question?

Comment: I thought about this as well. Django backend. Just checking is there was anything I could do on the frontend

Comment: I'd have to see your code, but I would assume a solution would involve `json.dumps(Post.objects.all())`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a name attribute to your hidden tag.

The name is what you refer to it by.

```
<input type="hidden" name="payload" id="payload">
```