# Why is document.DOM-object.property null in legacy application

Tags: javascript, legacy-code

I can't find a plausible explanation for the following behaviour of javascript code. 
I am not very familiar with javascript and if the following code was ever valid.

In a migrated legacy application there is code along those lines:

```
function myFunctionName(name)
{
    for(k=0; k < document.budget_sections.length; ++k) {
    //...do something
    }
}
```

Please note the `document.budget_sections.length` part. In production this code throws an error saying cannot access property length of null. In my dev environment this runs fine. 
Since `budget_sections` is the Id of a form element (`<form id="budget_sections" method="post" runat="server">`)I changed the code to the syntax which is known to me:

```
function myFunctionName(name)
{
    var form = document.getElementById("budget_sections");
    for(k=0; k < form.length; ++k) {
    //...do something
    }
}
```

This syntax / notation is used throughout the whole application and works on most pages. The question for me here is: why did and still does this old code work and why might it break now? I have never read the notation `document.DOM-object.xxx` before and I can't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since budget_sections is the Id of a  element

Nope, it's name of the form.

```
document.formname.length
```

still works.

> I can't find documentation about it.

Here is one such example in MDN for `document.images.length`

**[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images)**

All these are `properties` in your `document`. You can read more about it in that page left sidebar. You will find documentation for all of the properties similar to `document.DOM_Object.property`

Comment: This clears things up a bit. But I worte Id correctly. It is defined as `<form id="budget_sections" runat="server">` and not as name.

Comment: You can give it a shot. Create a form with `id="budget_sections" ` and another form with `name="budget_sections"`. The DOM specification allows only `name` attribute to be reference not the ID

Answer (score 1):

I think that is old notation. If you set name attribute of your forms to "budget_sections" instead of id then it will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="xx">
  Form 1
</form>
<form name="xx">
  Form 2
</form>

<button onclick="alert(document.xx.length)">Number of forms</button>

</body>
</html>
```

or you can get same result with forms instead of name value:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="xx">
  Form 1
</form>
<form name="xx">
  Form 2
</form>

<button onclick="alert(document.forms.length)">Number of forms</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have explanation about ID and name attribute on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Comment: From what I take here, the original creator of this code has messed up ID and Name and it somehow worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should use if I remember my IE6 days correctly document.forms['budget_sections'] to get the form items...

There was a difference between how IE and Netscape handled things. But i'm not sure since that was more than 15 years ago heh.