# use the name attribute to reference an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

To get a collection of element we use the getElementsByName() method.Then we can use it to reference individual elements using indexes [0,1,2,...].But i have an example where name attribute is directly used to indicate an iframe element.This is a new thing to me.I don't know what to google to find some articles about it.Can anyone explain to me what it is and under which circumstances i can use this type of reference method.

i mean here `mask.document.designMode` is directly using the name attribute to reference the ifram.Shouldn't it be `document.getElementById('mask').document.designMode` ?

My code enables the designmode for the iframe element.It works in my browsers but not sure why not working in SO's editor.

```js
function iframeOn(){
  mask.document.designMode='on';
 
}
```

```html
<iframe name='mask' id='mask' onload='iframeOn();' style='border:1px solid black;width:700px;height:300px;word-wrap:break-word;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-bottom:2px;overflow-y:scroll;' ></iframe>
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure its the name attribute and not the ID attribute?  2)  Are you running any other code (like libraries) on your page where it's working that might not be coming along for the ride onto SO?  If the answer to the 2nd question is "no" then I suggest looking for document.getElementById()

Comment: Yes, it's a way to refer `window` objects. Notice, that using `name` will refer to the `window` within the `iframe`, `iframe` element itself (given by `gEBI()`) has not `document` object.

Comment: @DaveKaye yup ,i am pretty sure :). it is running on my browser right now.

Comment: @Teemu you seems to understand my question.can you elaborate it ? or post an well explained answer ?still not clear to me

Comment: @AL-zami I tried to find some good documentation about use of the `name`, but no luck so far. Anyway, I'd recall I've read, in context of  `name` attribute was declared deprecated, something like it would still be valid when using with `window` objects and `form` elements and few other tags only. This was a couple of years ago, things might have been changed after that. A handy way would be to use [`frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) collection.

Comment: @AL-zami Well, at least [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) lists the elements you can apply `name` attribute ...

Comment: @AL-zami so then the 2nd part of my comment applies, as mentioned in the answer just below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be document.getElementById('mask').document.designMode

No.  it should be

```
 var iframe=document.getElementById("mask");
 var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDocument .designMode....
```

`getElementById('mask')` gives you an Iframe element which you need its window/contentWindow  object which has document which now you can do whatever you want.

Comment: thanks !  i understand the gEBI() part.But what about using the name directly?

Comment: @AL-zami Don't use it via name. use it strictly as you should. I've seen this when acceesing a form attributes. but it's not safe. since there might be overrides. read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

Comment: This is what I was saying to you in my comment above.  It's the ID not the name that you're working with here.  And yes, don't work with name.  It can change context, and there are other reasons.