# PHP wont echo name from form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form as shown below.

```
<form role="form-horizontal" method="post" action="pacific.php" style="width 70%">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Name:</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next ></button>
</form>
```

It submits `name` to `pacific.php`. On `pacific.php` I have php code first getting the input from `name` and then I have an `echo` statement as show below.

```
<?php
$n = $_POST["name"];
echo "Hello, $n.";
?>
```

Yet on the page, all it echos is "Hello, .". I'd like it to echo "Hello, (persons name)."

Comment: Add "name" attribute in your input . <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">

Comment: It's missing the `name` attribute... The `id` is a different thing.. So, `name="somename"` and then `$_POST['somename']`. Read more about [**Difference between id and name attributes in HTML**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1397592/4577762)

Comment: Please add a attribute name="name" in your input

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add name to the desired input

```
<form role="form-horizontal" method="post" action="pacific.php" style="width 70%">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Name:</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" name="name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next ></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
```

change to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
```

you need to use `name` attribute, while posting a form PHP requests names of inputting elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to be this way: `name="name"` is required to capture data using post method.

```
<form role="form-horizontal" method="post" action="pacific.php" style="width 70%">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Name:</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next ></button>
</form>


<?php
$n = $_POST["name"];
echo "Hello, $n.";
?>
```