# simple POST method not working

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've created an account just so I could ask this question: Why is the post method not working on these simples files?

Code on file 1:

```
<form method="POST" action="caralho.php">
        <input type="text" id="titulo_cardapio" />
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

file 2, "caralho.php":

```
<?php
$crlh = $_POST['titulo_cardapio'];
echo $crlh;
?>
```

This simple form somehow does not post the variables, when I load "caralho.php", after clicking the submit button, this happens:

Notice: Undefined index: titulo_cardapio in C:\xampp\htdocs\cardapio\caralho.php on line 2

HOW is this happening? This is driving me insane

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input needs the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="titulo_cardapio" name="titulo_cardapio" />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Oh my god... I've done this 1000 times in the past but still missed. About 4h of thinking and testing. Thank you!

Comment: It's so simple. :)