# Naming convention for the "id" vs "name" attribute on HTML form elements when submitting data

Tags: html, forms, naming

Is there a suggested naming convention for HTML form element IDs vs. the *name* attribute?

I am referring specifically to when submitting the form and using jQuery.serializeArrays() to capture the data which appears to give {"name":"", "value":""} pairs.

Comment: I've raised the 'primarly opinion based' flag on your question pre-edit, but since it's now edited, it's more a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Comment: Hi @Roberrrt thanks for the reply. I have just read that question, but I'm interested not in the difference but in the naming and there seems to be conflicting answers. The primary point of the question is not about naming but that id is for DOM ident and name is for posting form data.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can find Google's style guide here:

*[4.1.2 ID and Class Naming](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#ID_and_Class_Naming)*

Comment: The actual link: https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is what is the name convention for the name attribute of an HTML form element.

Comment: I agree. This is not helpful as it doesn't answer OP's question.