# Trouble interpreting <input> elements especially name and id

Tags: html, web

I'm still a beginner and am still learning how to read and understand HTML. Within a login form in a website:

```
<form action="https://examplesite.jp/user.php" name="loginform" method="post">

<ul class="form">
<li class="title">E-MAIL ADDRESS</li>
<li class="text"><input type="text" name="uname" 
id="legacy_xoopsform_block_uname" size="18" maxlength="60" value=""/>
</li>

<li class="title">PASSWORD</li>
<li class="pass">

<input type="password" name="pass" id="legacy_xoopsform_block_pass" 
size="18" maxlength="12"/>
```

Part I do not understand is this part from above:

```
<input type="password" name="pass" id="legacy_xoopsform_block_pass" 
size="18" maxlength="12"/>
```

I understand up to `<input type="password" name="pass" />` part, but not after that especially how it's using `id="legacy_xoopsform_block_pass"`.

How I am comprehending this code is that the type of input that will be sent to https:/examplesite.jp/user.php (using online form) is "password", and that is named "pass" but what's "id"? Especially email's acted as ID?

I read [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html) but don't really understand...

Comment: this is markup, not code.

Comment: The name attribute is the key that the data will be assigned when it's posted to the other page, an ID is just for identification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID attribute isn't used for any server side function, it is merely for styling (ill-advised) or more commonly used for hooking JavaScript functionality too.

So for example, you could use it to style the element in your CSS:

```
#legacy_xoopsform_block_uname {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Or you could use it to do stuff in JavaScript:

```
$('#legacy_xoopsform_block_uname').on('click', function(){
  alert('the input field has just been clicked);
});
```

Those are the only two situations you would use the ID, however I don't suggest the first option, I would use a class for that.

Essentially if you're not doing one of the above two things, you don't need and can safely get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Please use google search, its your best friend!

In the CSS, a class selector is a name preceded by a full stop (“.”) and an ID selector is a name preceded by a hash character (“#”). The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

[Source](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/)

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute value is a name of a query parameter. This is a name of data field, that will sent to server with your form. `id` is an unique identidicator of HTML element. There is no several elements with same `id` in valid HTML. Thus, [`id` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) is used for HTML element identification, but the [`name` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name) is used for data field identification in HTTP request.