# Disable button if one radio is checked

Tags: javascript

I have three radio each one has name started with `delivery_option` and a submit button with css class `continue`. I want to  test if a radio is checked the button must be enabled, otherwise it should be disabled.

i made the code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkout-delivery-step input:radio').each(function() {
    if ($("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']:checked").length != 0) {
      $('.continue').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('.continue').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

but it does not work, what was the issue?

Comment: Please share your complete code (at least the HTML for the button and radios).

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the code only *once*. The code has to be run **every time when the `radio` button is clicked or changed**. So you need to use the following:

```js
// Make this a function.
function checkProgress() {
  if ($("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']:checked").length != 0) {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', true);
  }
}

$(function () {
  // Set the status once the doc loads.
  checkProgress();
  // Set it again when any of the radio buttons are clicked.
  $("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']").on("click change", checkProgress);
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
// Make this a function.
function checkProgress() {
  if ($("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']:checked").length != 0) {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.continue').prop('disabled', true);
  }
}

$(function () {
  // Set the status once the doc loads.
  checkProgress();
  // Set it again when any of the radio buttons are clicked.
  $("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']").on("click change", checkProgress);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Group 1</h3>

Option 1: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_1" />
Option 2: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_1" />
Option 3: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_1" />

<h3>Group 2</h3>

Option 1: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_2" />
Option 2: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_2" />
Option 3: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option_2" />

<p>Submit?</p>

<input type="button" value="Submit" class="continue" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) which will remove the attribute from any element which is already set.

Also, for the radio you can do this way, once it is clicked then you can enable the button because it doesn't provide a way to deselect it.

Finally, the name for elements can be the same if it is a group and only the id must be unique. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html).

So, proper code will be

```
<label for="delivery_option1">Option1:</label><input type="radio" id="delivery_option1" name="delivery_option" />
<label for="delivery_option2">Option2:</label> <input type="radio" id="delivery_option2" name="delivery_option" />
<label for="delivery_option3">Option3:</label><input type="radio" id="delivery_option3" name="delivery_option" />
```

```js
$(function(){

      $("input:radio[name*='delivery_option']").click(function(){
      
        $(".continue").removeAttr("disabled");
      
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Option1: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option1" />
Option2: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option2" />
Option3: <input type="radio" name="delivery_option3" />

<input type="button" value="Submit" class="continue" disabled />
```

Comment: Er... You have a small mistake. `:)` The `name` should be same.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, Please check my updates, as you've used `name*='delivery_option'` thought you understand the name will be different

Comment: Boss, that's because of ... Well, now you figured out... Semma! `:)`