# How to Save a Role from Thymeleaf using in Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

**Hello buddies, i have two models, User and Role. i have inserted three roles(ADMIN, CUSTOMER, DEALER) in table Roles. I have made these roles available to Thymeleaf User Type field to be chosen during registration.**

**Controller Model Attribute for roles.**

@ModelAttribute("roles")

```
public List<Role> initializeRoles(){
    List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findAll();

    return roles ;
}
```

**Then here is my thymeleaf to display the available roles for user to choose during registration.**

```
 <div class="col-1.5">
        <label th:for="roles"> User Type: </label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="agentName">
            <option value="">Select User Type</option>
            <option th:each="initializeRoles:${roles}"
                    th:value="${initializeRoles.id}"
                    th:text="${initializeRoles.name}"
            >
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**Finally here is my User Service to submit registration data input by the user:**

```
public void save(User user) {
        user.setEnabled(false);
        user.setPword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPword()));
        user.setRoles(user.getRoles());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

i'm expecting the role selected from user type field to be submitted and assigned as a role to that user. however, the rest of user data is successfully persisted except the selected role. Where i'm i going wrong?

[image: The database output after data is submitted to my tables.]

Comment: I think you are missing name attribute within <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="agentName"> tag . try with providing a name="roles"

Comment: Thank you @R.G , that was the problem and now it is working. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `name` missing from the select tag

Following will fix the issue

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="roles" id="agentName">
```

Comment: why is the name attribute soo important than th:value element. this is working perfect yeah

Comment: name attribute is used in a form submission. You can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Comment: th:value here sets the value for options available . When the form gets submitted , the selected option (value) among the options , will be submitted with the name of the select tag .