# Should I use name attribute in bootstrap from?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I have used bootstrap for a school project and got this as a mistake so I would like to understand what is the error.
It's about the use of forms.
In the [w3c html documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) there is a use of name attribute:

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

While in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/), there isn't

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Do I have to add those attribute myself or should it be use as is with bootstrap ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html) may help you understand.

Comment: @SameerKhan indeed, got it, thank you.