# Thymeleaf form sumbit button always returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have the following login template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- LOGIN -->
    <section id="login-section" class="mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4>Account Login</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username and password</div>
                                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out</div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pass">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkRememberMe" name="checkRememberMe">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkRememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    ....
```

Upon clicking the submit button, I expect the user to be authenticated. However, on the console I get a null pointer exception. Turns out, it is returning a null value. Is there anything wrong with this part of the code?

Thank you

PS: I'll add the remaining involved code just in case the error is there:

User entity:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String username;

    private String pass;

    private String roles;

    private String permissions;

    public List<String> getRoleList() {
        if(this.roles.length() > 0) {
            return Arrays.asList(this.roles.split(","));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<String> getPermissionList() {
        if(this.permissions.length() > 0) {
            return Arrays.asList(this.permissions.split(","));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Security configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    //AUTHENTICATION
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    //AUTHORIZATION
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/secret").hasAnyRole(ADMIN_ACCESS, CLIENT_USER, CLIENT_ADMIN)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("pass")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(600).key("secretKey").rememberMeParameter("checkRememberMe");
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Front controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainFrontController {
    // Login form
    @GetMapping("login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("Acceso a login");
        return "comun/login.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("home")
    public String home(Model model){
        return "comun/home";
    }
}
```

User repository:

````java
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Integer> {
    Usuario findByUsername(String username);
}

User details
```java

public class GroupUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Usuario user;

    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public GroupUserDetails(Usuario usuario) {
        this.user = usuario;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        //Extract permissions
        this.user.getPermissionList().forEach(p -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        //Extract roles
        this.user.getRoleList().forEach(r -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPass(); // <== This is where it crashes 
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
````

User details service

```java
@Service
public class GroupUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nombre) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario user = repository.findByUsername(nombre);
        GroupUserDetails guser = new GroupUserDetails(user);

        return guser;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the stacktrace

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at net.secret.apidbcliente.comun.security.GroupUserDetails.getPassword(GroupUserDetails.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_281]
```

Comment: Does a user with the given name (I think you locally deploy and "test"?) exist? Because: If no user exists with the given name, for me the exception is correct (if `GroupUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` returns `null`).

Comment: I know what a null pointer is, I wanted to know why the html was sending a null object when the inputs where correctly filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may come from the HTML tag your are using in the login template:

Replace id="username" by name="username" and id="pass" by name="pass".
More info on name an id tags in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)