# My HTML button is not working, or it wont call my javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding, and i am trying to make a game in javascript. I don't know why my HTML button is not calling my javascript function. I have tried moving the button to the bottom of the code, I have tried it with different functions, I have looked on some reference sites and i can't figure out why it is not working. Here is my button:

```js
let waveActive = false;
let waveNumber = 0;
let enemyCount = 4;
let enemyAmount = 0;
let enemyHealth = 30;

function newWave() {
  enemyCount + 25 %
    Math.floor(enemyCount);
  enemyHealth + 10 %
    Math.floor(enemyHealth);
}

function startWave() {
  waveNumber + 1;
  waveActive = true;
  newWave()
  class enemySpawn {
    main(Stringargs) {
      int(i = enemyAmount)
      while (i < enemyCount) {
        Enemy = new component(30, 30, "purple", 10, 120);
        enemyAmount + 1;
      }
    }
    enemyAmount = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div name="buttonDiv">
  <button type="button" id="startRoundBtn" onclick=startWave();>Start Round</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ??? `onclick=startWave();` needs quotes around the function. `enemyCount + 25%` what is that supposed to be? What part isn't working? Have you put `console.log()` statements around to determine which line is breaking?

Comment: @Kinglish — *onclick=startWave(); needs quotes around the function* — No, quotes are optional there.

Comment: I've no idea what you expect that code to do. Nothing you have looks like it is supposed to output anything anywhere.

Comment: Yes it works without quotes although ugly.

Comment: This isn't a big problem, but for your container div, I suggest you give it an id instead of a name attribute because those are typically used for forms. See the [difference between the id attribute and the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html).

Comment: `enemyAmount + 1;` and `waveNumber + 1;` do nothing. Not sure what `int()` is supposed to be. Not sure how the code would ever get out of the while block

Answer (score 1):

Try to increment your wave number. `waveNumber + 1` will not change the property.

```js
waveNumber += 1;
```

Here too (along with other places):

```js
function newWave() {
  enemyCount = enemyCount + 25 %
    Math.floor(enemyCount);
  enemyHealth = enemyHealth + 10 %
    Math.floor(enemyHealth);
}
```

The other issue is your class definition inside your click handler.

You probably do not need the `main` function.  It seems you want something more like this

```js
class EnemySpawn {
  constructor(...args) {
     // do stuff here
  }
}

enemyAmount = 0;  // not sure if you even want to reset this...

while (enemyAmount < enemyCount) {
 const enemy = new EnemySpawn(30, 30, "purple", 10, 120);
 enemyAmount += 1;
}
```

Comment: That's the least of the problems with this code, and won't make a difference since nothing else ever reads that value.

Comment: @Quentin It's certain a issue that can be corrected.

Comment: Answers are supposed to completely answer the question though. [Not all questions can or should be answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Try it in Script tag in html it should work. Below code is working for me :)

```
<div name="buttonDiv">
  <button type="button" id="startRoundBtn" onclick="startWave();">
    Start Round
  </button>
</div>

<script>
    let waveActive = false;
let waveNumber = 0;
let enemyCount = 4;
let enemyAmount = 0;
let enemyHealth = 30;
function newWave() {
enemyCount + 25%
Math.floor(enemyCount);
enemyHealth + 10%
Math.floor(enemyHealth);
}
function startWave() {
  waveNumber + 1;
  waveActive = true;
  newWave()
  class enemySpawn {
     main(Stringargs) {
        int(i = enemyAmount)
        while (i < enemyCount) {
            Enemy = new component(30, 30, "purple", 10, 120);
            enemyAmount + 1;
       }
    }
    enemyAmount = 0;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I click the button, nothing happens. How is that "working"?