# I am unable to get the values from a form from cshtml page to my controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am getting null values in my controller after the form is submitted to the code

```
<form action="Home/Book" method="Post">
   <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
   <input id="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
   <input id="Number"type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
   <textarea id="Comment" placeholder="comment here"></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my controller code

```
public IActionResult Book(Book obj)
{
string name =obj.Name;
name = name + "testing if value is there";
return View();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBEc7.png)

Comment: Your fields have IDs but lack names. [Difference between id and name attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `name` attribute to bind data in the form, please change your input to:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
```

or if you are using asp.net core mvc, You can use tag hepler `asp-for`,change your input to:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Name" placeholder="Name">
```

`asp-for="Name"` will generate to `id="Name" name="Name"`  automatically in html.

Answer (score 0):

You should set HttpPost attribute for your action. By default, the action seems to be the get method, not the post method. do like this:

```
**[httpPost]**
public IActionResult Book(Book obj)
{
string name =obj.Name;
name = name + "testing if value is there";
return View();
}
```

Comment: still not working after adding [httpPost] attribute